# How to test touch events using desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, touch-event

I want to write some test cases for touch events. In my code I have the following logic to decide whether it is on touch devices.

```
if(document.documentElement.ontouchstart !== undefined)
{
 //content that I want to write test cases about
}
```

Now I want to fake `document.documentElement.ontouchstart` not to be `undefined`, so the inside logic will be executed.

I tried using `Sinon.js`'s `stub` to assign an empty function to `document.documentElement.ontouchstart`. But it will throw an error indication "TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property `ontouchstart`as function" since `document.documentElement` has no such property in browser.

I really don't want to write something like: `document.documentElement.ontouchstart = function() {..}` in my test since it will effect other test cases. Of course I can store the original value of it and restore the value when the test case is over. But I wanna to ask, is there any more elegant way to achieve this?

How to make it to go into `if` statement?

Comment: you can call/trigger for onmousedown event ontouchstart

Comment: @ABUdhay But I want to check the logic inside `if`. Triggering `onmousedown ` won't let the `if` statement becomes true.

Comment: That's what basically in Dom it won't be there.. you have add a method to domelement object like document.documentElement.ontouchstart = function(){//Here you have to call the callback function of onmousedown or trigger mousedown event handler method}

Comment: @ABUdhay Yes, that's what I write for now. Hope there will be other options.

Answer (score 4):

use Chrome's device tool, toggling by activating this button in developer's tool.

**as image**
[image]

This allows you to debug like in a mobile environment.

Comment: In this way, `document.documentElement.ontouchstart` is still `undefined`. And even it is defined in this way, I can never tell `qunit` to run test cases in this way.