# Can I use `Sinon` to fake an undefined property?

Tags: javascript, sinon

I understand `stub` is to use when I want to replace the original function with a new one.

```
sinon.stub(A, 'b', function(){
  //fake
})
```

But it only works when `b` is a property of `A`. Is there any way to fake `A.b` no matter `b` exists?

I know I can do something like:

```
var original = A.b;
A.b = function() {
    //fake
}
.... test cases...
A.b = original; // restore the original value
```

Is there more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious - why?

Comment: @MikeMoore you can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161397/how-to-test-touch-events-using-desktop-browser

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a more elegant way, but I also don't think you need sinon for this:

```
obj.stub = function () { //... };
// test stuff
delete obj.stub;
```

Comment: So what's the difference between your answer and my second code block? Besides, you could not just delete it, what if it has a value before your stub?

Comment: So, you don't have control over `A`? I guess I'm assuming you are writing automated tests, where you have control over whether objects have properties or not.

Comment: If I have control over `A`, I can just use `stub` :)

Comment: I guess I don't understand. Do you or do you not have control over `A`? Maybe you can write a condition to check if property `b` exists. If it exists, use sinon, if it doesn't don't use sinon... just trying to help. Perhaps you could clarify your original question.

Comment: The original question is I'm testing some use cases about touch events, in browser. In browser, `document.documentElement.ontouchstart` is `undefined`. But I have to test some logic when it is defined. So come back to this question, `A.b` does not exist here. Your answer does work, but it is same as my second code block. I'm trying to find out some other solution. Thanks for your patience and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, in regards to the `ontouchstart` event, you might want to look into mocking it so it exists when you need it, or possibly emulation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121985/discussion-between-mike-moore-and-jasmineot).